# Spring Boot Actuator not working- Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Spring Boot **Actuator** is not working for rest-full application, getting Whitelabel Error Page on browser and below error in console log.

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler found for GET /actuator/health
```

Added below maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I cross checked, jar file available in class path.[image]

Spring boot application version

```
<version>2.4.1</version>
```

Added properties in application.properties file

```
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true
management.endpoint.info.enabled=true
management.security.enabled=false
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

Unable to access Actuator with below URL's

```
http://localhost:8090/actuator/health
http://localhost:8090/actuator/
http://localhost:8090/health/
```

Logs

```
WARN IN-WKS-435 [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.w.s.PageNotFound                     : No mapping for GET /actuator/health
WARN IN-WKS-435 [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.w.s.PageNotFound                     : No handler found for GET /actuator/health
WARN IN-WKS-435 [nio-8090-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler found for GET /actuator/health]
```

Note: Apart from this, whole application is working fine.

Kindly suggest if I need to add any additional configuration in our application.

Comment: Please check next few points:
1. if there is `management.server.port` configuration value in properties? It will change the port where actuator is accessible
2. Logs of application upon call - to see if there are no errors
3. On startup of application please check log line `Exposing 14 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'` - to double-check that such endpoints are actually exposed. Hope this helps to identify the root cause

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for your prompt response, on startup I could not see Exposing 14 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'. I just edited the post and added logs as well.

Comment: Can you see the actuator in external libraries? Maybe somehow it isn't added correctly @VivekJain

Comment: [dextertron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3079891/dextertron) I verified , it's available in class path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot Actuators endpoints could not be picked-up if running within IDE(IntelliJ or Eclipse).

I tried to run jar using below command(outside of IDE) on cmd and it worked for me.

`c:\workspace\demo\target\java -jar demo-spring-boot-project.jar`

And I was able to access below URL

http://localhost:8090/actuator/health

Answer (score 4):

Encountered this too while running the app through InteliJ IDEA.
It turns out I added the spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency but did not tell Maven to reload the project.

Right clicking on the pom.xml file and selecting Maven->Reload project, solved it.

*In this case I see the jar file exists in your classpath, so your problem is different than mine.
Leaving this comment so it might help someone else.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same issue while running the project through IntelliJ IDE.
I resolved after doing `Invalidate Cache & Restart` in IntelliJ IDE.

Go to `File` -> ``Invalidate Cache`.

The Invalidate cache dialog box appears. One can select accordingly to their project.

Answer (score -1):

It requires a dependency for auto configuring Actuator.
Below is the dependency you need to add.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to update the maven Project ,
if you are using Eclipse IDE go to  Project ->  Update Maven Project
Select all Check boxes Except Offline and the click ok.
it will update maven Dependency.
Hope it Fixed Your Problem.